# square root of a log argument not unique?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I am confused by the following two approaches

\begin{align}
\frac{i}{2}\left(\log(ia+w)-\log(ia-w)\right)&=\frac{i}{2}\log\frac{ia+w}{ia-w}\\
&=\frac{i}{2}\log\frac{(ia+w)^2}{\color{red}{i^2}(a^2+w^2)}\\
&=i\log\frac{w+ia}{\color{red}{i}\sqrt{a^2+w^2}}\\
&=i\log\frac{a-iw}{\sqrt{a^2+w^2}}\\
&=i\log e^{-i\tan^{-1}\frac{w}{a}}=\tan^{-1}\frac{w}{a}
\end{align}
**Mistake in red fixed!**

\begin{align}
\frac{i}{2}\left(\log(ia+w)-\log(ia-w)\right)&=\frac{i}{2}\left[\log\left(i(a-iw)\right)-\log\left(i(a+iw)\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{i}{2}\left[\frac{i\pi}{2}+\log(a-iw)-\frac{i\pi}{2}-\log(a+iw)\right]\\
&=i\log\left[\frac{a-iw}{\sqrt{a^2+w^2}}\right]\\
&=i\log e^{i\tan^{-1}\frac{-w}{a}}=\tan^{-1}\frac{w}{a}
\end{align}

Comment: maybe read about complex logarithm in wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm

Comment: There's a missing $\log(-1)$ term in the first approach, due to$$(ia-w)(ia+w)=i^2a^2-w^2=\color{red}{(-1)}(a^2+w^2)$$

Comment: @user170231, Thank you for your spotting.

Comment: I do not know if this is any problem in some text book. However I strongly recommend you just like trula to go through complex logarithms and complex inverse trigonometric functions. If $\log$ represented the principal branch of logarithm in your question, then the answer is simply $\frac{1}{2}\left( Arg(ia-w) - Arg(ia + w)\right)$.